# grails and AJAX dynamic search

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy

I want to organize search by users usernames.
When I write some letters, I want to see list of users, 
which usernames start  with that letters.
After clicking one of values I have to update users data.

Is there any easy plugin or other way to do it?

I use grail-1.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to catch the keypress event at the text box: after the user has type, says, 2 letters, use ajax/jQuery to send a request to the server. Then the server perform searching the database and return a list of approriate user.

I once used [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin, and the result is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

You may use JQuery Autocomplete to implement such feature... [Have a look at the demo](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete#Example)..

Answer (score 1):

The Grails UI plugin has autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery autocomplete can be a solution... check this link [Using Grails with jQuery Autocomplete](http://jay-chandran.blogspot.mx/2011/09/using-grails-with-jquery-autocomplete.html)

There is a demo for using autocomplete in a Grails application.